# Python async loop concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, aiohttp

I'm trying to extract datas from a group of URLs in an async way. I want to perform the requests by group of URLs every 10s(more or less).

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

from aiohttp import ClientSession


def create_list_urls():
    list_urls = [["http://apiexample.com/param1", "http://apiexample2.com/param1"],
                 ["http://apiexample.com/param2", "http://apiexample2.com/param2"]]
    return list_urls

async def retrieve_datas(url, session):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.json()


async def main():
    while True:
        urls_to_crawl = create_list_urls()
        for urls in urls_to_crawl:
            tasks = []
            async with ClientSession() as session:
                for url in urls:
                    tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(
                        retrieve_datas(url, session)))
                datas_extracted = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=False)
                print(datas_extracted)
         asyncio.sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(main())
    loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

But I'm receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 34, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(future)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 466, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 293, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 241, in _step
    result = coro.throw(exc)
  File "test.py", line 27, in main
    datas_extracted = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 380, in __iter__
    yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 304, in _wakeup
    future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 293, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "test.py", line 14, in retrieve_datas
    async with session.get(url) as response:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 603, in __aenter__
    self._resp = yield from self._coro
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 231, in _request
    conn = yield from self._connector.connect(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 378, in connect
    proto = yield from self._create_connection(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 687, in _create_connection
    _, proto = yield from self._create_direct_connection(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 698, in _create_direct_connection
    hosts = yield from self._resolve_host(req.url.raw_host, req.port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 669, in _resolve_host
    self._resolver.resolve(host, port, family=self._family)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aiohttp/resolver.py", line 31, in resolve
    host, port, type=socket.SOCK_STREAM, family=family)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 673, in getaddrinfo
    host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 634, in run_in_executor
    executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'max_workers'
```

So my question is how to fix it but more, I'm thinking I'm not doing the async in the right way. The strange issue is, if I'm using my IDE to manuely iterate(debug step by step), I can perform one iteration(receive datas of the first URLs group) before the error raise but if I execute directly this code the exception fire instantly.

EDIT:

If I'm using python 3.6 the exception disapears... The code is working except that the asyncio.sleep(10) is not executed(???) My code never sleep. If I replace asyncio.sleep(10) by time.sleep(10) it works. I think I've missed something. My issue is solved but if someone can explain me why this behavior about sleeping and globally if my code is correct to doing async requests.

Comment: what version of `aiohttp` are you using?

Comment: I've the version: 2.2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is raised not by `aiohttp` but by `asyncio` itself and it is very strange because the code is test covered.

What python version do you use? Is it custom build?

Regarding to `asyncio.sleep()` -- put `await` before the call.

Comment: arg... I forget the await :( Thanks Andrew. For my python version: Python 3.5.3 and the code is working with Python 3.6.2

Comment: On 3.5.3 `max_workers` parameter is not required:
The parameter was mandatory in Python 3.4 but it is optional for 3.5+